# How to prevent Sympy from calculating degree in pow

Tags: sympy, pow

There is an expression:

```
3^(48*x)
```

Sympy on further calculations will convert it to:

```
79766443076872509863361^x
```

Perhaps there is some kind of flag that prohibits such horrors.

Comment: You didn't specify what function converts the expression to that form but the obvious answer is not to call that function. Otherwise you could wrap the expression  in `UnevaluatedExpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `simplify` is used it will cause that expansion. One way you can keep this from happening is to replace `48` with `Symbol("48")` so it is a variable. An UnevaluatedExpr will not be protected from the actions of `simplify` so that might be your only option.

```
>>> simplify(UnevaluatedExpr(2**(4*x))+1)
16**x + 1
>>> simplify(2**(Symbol('4')*x)+1)
2**(4*x) + 1
```